# Am i able to use my own seed i created on Minecraft PE 0.15.3 on another platform

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

Ok i created a cool world on Minecraft PE. My question is, can i use that exact seed on a different platform like xbox one.

Comment: You are able to export the world as a file and then you can access it from a PC.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the unified/bedrock/pocket edition of Minecraft (different names for the same thing) and it has the same version number as your Minecraft PE installation, then it should be the same.

But there's also a separate (legacy) console edition of Minecraft. If you have that, you will not get the same result.